# How to set editor of pentadactyl on Mac?

Tags: macos, vim, firefox-extensions, pentadactyl

Firefox plugin `pentadactyl` provides the function of setting a external editor.

```
default: gvim -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>
```

I installed MacVim on my MacBook,

when I set editor like this, get an error:

```
set editor='macvim -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>'

Command not found: macvim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`macvim` is not an executable in your `$PATH` but you can use the `mvim` script bundled with MacVim.

1. Place the `mvim` script in your `$PATH`
2. Use this setting:

   ```
   set editor='mvim -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>'
   ```

You can also use the `open` command native to Mac OS X like that:

```
set editor='open -a macvim -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and romainl's solution did not work for me.

The kind John-Galt from #pentadactyl at irc.oftc.net helped me.

My mvim executeable was located in ~/.bin/mvim. So I ran

```
:set editor='~/.bin/mvim -f +<line> +"sil! call cursor(0, <column>)" <file>'
```

Note that I typed the whole path to the mvim binary. I don't understand why this works, but it did.

This can of course be appended to your .pentadactylrc (without the ':').

Comment: I tried this, but it still throws the error "Command not found: gvim". Any way to edit the part where it assigns gvim as the editor, or other hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @SilasBarta Are you using Windows? It seems that Pentadactyl is unable to recognize paths (*especially if there's spaces*) to the editor of choice. Because what if gvim resides in a directory that isn't simply in `C:\gvim.exe`?